# How can I make my contributions to Public Domain under my specified license in Account Deletion?

Tags: support, copyright

I want to make sure that my contributions will benefit the community the time of my account deletion, not just Stackexchange so I would like to make it clear like Steve Jessop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop):

> All my original contributions to StackOverflow are hereby placed into
>   the public domain. If this is not legally possible, then anyone
>   receiving a copy of them by any means is granted a non-exclusive
>   perpetual license to use, distribute and modify them, and to
>   distribute modifications, under any license or none, with or without
>   attribution to me. Please note that this license applies only to my
>   original contributions - quoted material and edits by me to existing
>   material on StackOverflow are not my creations and I cannot grant
>   rights in them.

Shortly, I am getting fed up to this: they drive you out of the site and then they get all rights over your material after anonymization, good ploy. So

How can I specify the license with anonymized account?

Comment: I repeat **`I want my account and material in that will be handled in Freedom-respecting way so anyway could make it better without attributions -- and if anonymity cannot be achieved, it is unfortunate.`**

Comment: Did you really do something so spectacular that this is necessary?  I mean, frankly, you only have 17 answers, only one of which has more than 2 upvotes.  And, the one that has more than 2 upvotes will be completely out of date in a year or two because it is based on technology.  Your reputation is 1/100th of Steve Jessop, and his is completely based on answers.

Comment: @Graphth Is there something bad in having good examples such as Steve? Asking questions is sometimes far more than solving the problems, personally, I love to ask -- you can, of course, do it with different style. Sure I have to work more on answers in the future, thank you for the notice, but here a question about principles: I want my contributions require **no attributions**, not to SE and not to me. Of course, it is cool if they are made but I don't want to force people to make arbitrary attributions like `"fish is fishing in fish-pond"`. It is my right but currently made blurry in profile

Answer (score 16):

hhh,

You are still the copyright owner of your work, so  you are still free to do whatever you wish with the original work. **You own your work always and forever** under copyright law. We have not nor can not take that away from you.

[Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) is just a license that says you agreed (through the license) to let us use this stuff, too. No ownership has changed hands. We in turn agree (under Creative Commons) to **extend those terms to anyone else** who agrees to those terms (reuse). That's so someone down the line can never claim your work under as their own (or make it more restricted).

However, a Creative Commons license is *perpetual.* That means you cannot come to us or all the folks down the line who agreed to reuse and say, *"Hey, I change the terms and don't want this to be Creative Commons anymore."* That's what perpetual means.

If you decide one day that you no longer wish to have your name associated with the work you licensed, Creative Commons allows for that, too. Section 4(c) or the Creative Commons license says that you can remove your credit as Licensor to your work. That's what account deletion (in Stack Exchange Terms) does.

Through all this rigamarole and legal jargon, you are still the copyright owner of your work. You simply licensed it to us and everyone else for reuse. But you never gave up original ownership at all and you are still free to do whatever you wish with the original work. You're not even bound by the terms for reuse. You can write a book, place it the public domain… anything you want. But that doesn't change the terms here. It's still licensed under Creative Commons, but you yourself can do with it whatever you please outside the terms for which you licensed it here. It's your stuff.

Comment: ...you don't address the key thing about `"the must for attribution"`. Could you address that also? Why? And how to circumvent it as an original author for the benefit of community? I think you are aware that I have deleted accounts in similar cases where I don't have any respect to moderators that discriminate or patronize other people and me. In this kind of cases, particularly, I want to make sure the material is going to benefit community without **a must for references**, how can I do it?

Comment: @hhh As the copyright holder, you can post your content wherever you choose. Use whatever license you want (or place it in the public domain). But you can't change the licensing terms for the stuff posted here.

Comment: Yes this is what I suspected, you need to have **a separate content** host for your stuff in order to make the content under freedom-respecting license. **The profile with freedom-respecting -license does no make the content actually under it**: when it is here, it is always under the non-freedom-respecting license. So basically one has to set up competitive content-host for freedom-respecting material away from SE, thank you for clarification +1 -- I hope someone has done it, do you know any such content host?

Comment: **[IMPORTANT]** 
Is this statement `"But you can't change the licensing terms for the stuff posted here.".` false in the light of `"Any of the above conditions can be waived if you get permission from the copyright holder."`? So does it mean that I am able to revoke all rights from SE to use my contributions or what does it mean? What does the term `"wave"` mean? -1 unless clarified.

Comment: Where is this even stated in [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)? Regardless, "waive" does not mean "revoke." The share-alike agreement means anyone can use the content here with attribution. We don't waive that requirement; you can't revoke it. If you want to distribute your work somewhere else under different terms, please do so.

Comment: It is on your site linked, http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, and `"To waive something is to choose not to insist on something that you are entitled to insist on"` according to G.M. so actually it is possible by the license to `"waive"` rights? It is written there or am I misunderstanding something? What does it mean in practise? What is the difference between `"revoke"` and `"waive"`?

Comment: @hhh Thanks, that's a good link. Click on the 'waived' link and 'Learn more'. It's much more readable in plain English. *"Are you aware that CC licenses are not revocable? You are free to stop offering the work under a CC license at any time, but this will not affect the rights associated with any copies of your work already in circulation absent a breach by a particular licensee (which does not affect continual use of the work by other licensees)."*

Comment: Not totally right `"This License and the rights granted hereunder will terminate automatically upon any breach --"`, the section about termination. `"2. Fair Dealing Rights. Nothing in this License is intended to reduce, limit, or restrict any uses free from copyright or rights "` so if copyright -holders are not allowed to have their material under more freedom-respecting -license, they can terminate i.e. revoke the license, right? Can I now drop out the requirement for references in the license in my contributions, please.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is logically impossible.

1. You want your contributions to not carry any indication that you wrote them (that's what account deletion *means*).
2. You want your contributions to carry indication that they are available under a more permissive license than the SE default, *by virtue of being written by you*.

These two wishes are plainly in conflict with each other, and there is no conceivable way the website can behave such as to satisfy both of them simultaneously.

Comment: ...perhaps I could move the rights to some aggregator that keeps the material under its name so masking the genuine writer? I can understand this problem +1 but I don't see that it is impossible, you basically need a third-party in-between SE and users to get the rights and keep them under freedom-respecting license. +1 for constructive point. I would be much happier to know that my contributions will help other people without arbitrary constraits about attributions.

Comment: The third party would need to keep a record of your license grant -- otherwise they would be vulnerable to you later reneging on it and accusing them of copyright infringement when they "falsely" claim that the posts are in the public domain. But such record-keeping seem to be what you expressly do not want to happen since you want the postings to be dissociated from you.

Comment: I don't really care about anonymity, it is an option not must. I care that the material will be available in Freedom-respecting way to the next-generations and the next-next-...-one. I hope dreams come to reality such as [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/could-we-make-a-book-with-mse-answers). I don't want to give my working to bullies, I feel like giving up if I delete my account. I want my account and material in that will be handled in Freedom-respecting way so anyway could make it better without attributions -- and if anonymity cannot be achieved, it is unfortunate.

Comment: You don't seem to describe any reason to wish for your account to be deleted. If you let it hang around, it will give you a place to put your license grant, and everybody will be happy. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have deleted many accounts, a lot of good material to make it easier to maintain things -- I cannot concentrate on too many accounts and keep them high quality and update info etc. I would be much happier if I could move material under some safe-haven the material of which people could use as they wish without attributions.

Comment: You don't seem to describe any reason to wish for your account to be deleted.

Comment: I did not understand. I don't want to delete my account unless the material will go under freedom-respecting license without requiring attributions. Account deletion is an option but I don't like to do it, the material becomes easily ghost -material. By having proper license, I make sure I even myself is able to use the material without arbitrary attributions. If I delete my account, it is extremely hard to prove that I am the original author.

Comment: **Right now**, your profile page does not list any more permissive license grant than the standard CC-by-sa license. I don't understand why you worry about the status if you delete the account when your contributions are **currently** only available under CC-by-sa anyway. What's stopping you from granting something more permissive **now**, _without_ deleting your account if that is what you want to do?

Comment: It is not "account deletion", the profile page disappears after it and the license will be CC-by-sa i.e. requiring attributions.

Comment: **Right now** they don't allow me to have a freedom-respecting license :( ... I tried to change my profile but it is not appearing there, profile-hacking is not a good thing. It does not solve this problem of mistrust.

Comment: **Cannot you see that they are doing everything against this? Perhaps, I am becoming paranoid but I want to make sure sure no-one's freedom is endangered by my actions, I want to give them equal right without attributions to use my content. If they want to attribute me, they can do it but I don't want to force anyone. Besides, I don't like it that people using time to my content lose their very-well earned votes, it does no good.**

Comment: You're ranting and not making any sense. If you want to license your contributions under a more permissive license than the default one SE requires, go right ahead and do that. Nobody's stopping you.

Comment: *My profile is NOT updated even though I updated it, clear now? Is this a bug in SE, I doubt it.*

Comment: However, if you want SE to stop telling people that you wrote those posts, you **cannot logically expect them** to nevertheless **keep** telling people about your additional license grant. Either you have a profile or you don't, and if you explicitly want not to have one, that **logically implies** that you want no special treatment for your posts. Information about an additional license grant is a special treatment. You can have that, nobody's stopping you, unless you persist in wanting to have special treatment for your profile all while not having any profile at all .

Comment: What do you mean not updated? Your "about me" text is now different from what it was a few hours ago.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/5902/hhh <-- It is not getting updated over all my account like this.

Comment: And **License != Grant**.

Comment: What you want is to **grant** a **license** to your work that is more permissive than the license SE requires you to grant by default. One of these words is a verb, the other is a noun. In "license grant" the verb has been nouned, and the entire phrase denote the fact that a license has been granted, the action of granting a licence, and/or the text that describes this action.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, English is not my first language. I thought grant was more abusive word.

Comment: @hhh A couple of quick clarifications. (1) Your content here is always licensed for reuse. Deleting your account does not change that at all. (2) Neither you nor Stack Exchange can change the terms for which you licensed the content here. (3) You still (and always have) owned the original copyright of your work so you can do whatever you want with it elsewhere. See my response: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6294/69

Comment: @RobertCartaino the problem is that in deletion it can be extremely hard to prove identity because it tries to anonymize things (although not totally possible). Suppose I start to use my written material in deleted accounts without attributions to you (and I allow my friends/peers do the same )and you require us for attribution, how do you think I am going to prove that I am the original author? To have everything under Git while using SE/SO? I find it hilarious if I really had to have an extremely long reference -list, vacuous references are bad and doing that by must is worse.

Comment: File a copyright registration for your work through the Copyright Office (or whatever legal protection your local country provides). We've already licensed the work for re-distribution to guarantee access to the work. If you want to keep personal records of authorship after you wipe your account here, that's all on you.

Comment: @RobertCartaino precisely, you make it as hard as possible for people to rip out the attribution -requirement even for their own material. Thank you for clarification, clearly, co-operation is very one-sided. +1 for being honest. It would be much cooler for freedom-respecting deleted user to have a freedom -label to show no attribution required :)

Comment: @hhh: You're still wanting the impossible. On one hand you say "please don't provide me with any service in the future", but on the other hand "please do provide me the service of informing people on my behalf that I allow them to do various things with my postings". Do you want SE to do something for you or not?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have a feature request to make deleted-user logo with some freedom-picture when attributions not required. Users get deleted for different reasons: some do not want to co-operate with certain moderators, some just get fed up, etc -- making difference for the reason of deletion and show that in the deleted user picture would be cool.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is not impossible, it is a possible feature request :)

Comment: @hhh: that does not make sense. If your account is deleted, then **it doesn't exist** and therefore cannot display any custom logo. I don't grasp what you want to achieve by having your account deleted-but-not-really-deleted-anyway. What will this strange contradictory state give you that **simply ceasing to use the account** will not?

Comment: @HenningMakholm silent accounts are just clutter, deleted accounts are better in that case because then moderators can see that it is **unmaintained**, **maintained** accounts require continuous work to improve and get better, at least I try to do so. When I delete account, I signal that I have no interest to help the community at hand. I don't like to leave my account to get rotten, it requires continuous working and monitoring that quality stays high.

Comment: @hhh: A silent account would give you **exactly what you want**, namely the ability to tell readers of the site that you permit them to do things with your postings that other users may not permit for their postings. You can also write in the profile text that you're not planning to return, if you want to explicitly communicate that. This is **exactly the feature you want**, right there, ready to use, and for free! The fact that **THE FEATURE YOU WANT ALREADY EXISTS** is excellent reason not to want to spend developer time on implementing it all over.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is not, it is jailed to my Google Account that I cannot disassociate unless deletion. It is close but it is not the same. Profile changes are **reversible**, this kind of license things are **irreversible**.

Comment: @hhh: If that is true, it would be better to make a feature request of dissociation from the Google login, rather than a feature request for a "deleted, but not really deleted anyway" state for the account. And ***you are completely free NOT to attempt to reverse your licensing decision if you don't want to reverse it***.

Comment: @HenningMakholm perhaps good idea +1, someone has probably requested that already, the reason not to disassociate had something to do with the quality I think but anyway it has been requested but denied, will do some research on it later unless someone finds it before me.

Comment: ...anyway this kind of license does not make me much motivated to improve quality here, I would be much happier to know that my contributions will help everyone and not just a few elites but now I see that this discussion goes nowhere. They have chosen their license, totally up to them. I don't support the restriction in my work but I don't want to force my thinking on top of other people. I think their force is bad.

Comment: @hhh: Go ahead and be happy. ***Nobody is preventing you from allowing people to do more with your posts than the minimum amount required by CC-by-sa.*** Why do you persist in not understanding this EXTREMELY SIMPLE AND STRAIGHTFORWARD fact?

Comment: @HenningMakholm because I don't trust them at all, I have historical reasons for my mistrust that is not supported by odd moderators. Do not take anything at the face value here, the license is a question about principles: I have used to live in eqalitarian country, not discriminated by odd mods and odd rules.

Comment: You don't need to trust anyone. **You own the copyright to your own text**. There is no trust needed. If you choose to let people do more than CC-by-sa in itself allows them to, then **your decision is the legal fact**, and nothing SE does can take that choice away from you or from anyone else that does things based on that permission from you. SE's only role is that you have (already) allowed _them_ to reproduce the text, bit **you own the copyright** and are **completely free** to permit whoever you want to do whathever they or you want with the text.

Comment: The only thing here is that you're demanding that SE helps you **publicise** the fact that you're giving additional permission -- and they're in fact happy to do so, in that you can have a completely free profile page where such things can be publicised. The trouble is just that you want them to do you the service of publicising your additional permission **at the same time** as not doing you any service anymore.

Comment: **[IMPORTANT]** @HenningMakholm You don't understand what Robert wrote, `"But you can't change the licensing terms for the stuff posted here."`. It means you need to have **a separate content host** to make your stuff under freedom-respecting license. The profile-hacking does not change the license, you agreed with the license the moment you started to use this service. **The only way to make freedom-respecting SE material is to start up a separate content-host.** This is how I understand Robert's statement.

Comment: @hhh: No, that's not how copyright works. The license permissions to a text is _always_ what the copyright owner, i.e. you, say they are. This applies to _the text itself_ -- there's no such thing as license terms becoming unavailable simply because the text has been transmitted through this system or that. If you **give people the right** to do something with your text, **they have that right** no matter whether they got their copy of your text through a web server such as SE's ones that don't tell them about this. There's no such thing as "tainted bits" in copyright law. (...)

Comment: If I know you allow me to do something with your text, I have that right to your text independently of the mechanics by which I came in possession of a copy to do it to. What Robert meant with his answer is that you cannot _retract_ any of the rights you _already_ gave everyone (and promised would be there forever) when you posted your content under CC-by-sa. But there is no legal way for SE to prevent you from handing out _additional_ rights whenever you want, and those additional rights will also apply to copies of the content that have passed through SE's server.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is not additional! If I add an extra term that is conflicting with the first license i.e. requiring attribution. I think it is not much additional, it tries to revoke the original restriction, I see the only way to make the content under your own license like the above is to set up a new content-host with only your copyrighted-material. Even then I am skeptical whether I am able to do it or are they going to attack such content hosts with legal issues?

Comment: Also note that licensing content under CC-by-sa **does not mean that anyone is now forbidden to do something**. The role of a copyright license is to **allow** people to do things you could otherwise have sued them from. When Robert says that the license is "perpetual" what he means is that you must **continue** to allow these things. It doesn't mean that you cannot decide to allow **more** things than CC-by-sa says.

Comment: The effect of CC-by-sa is that **you have to allow copying with attribution**. If you also want to allow copying **without** attribution, CC-by-sa does not stop you. How it works is that CC-by-sa says that some things are now **allowed**, but it does not requires that attribution-less copying is now forbidden. Rather, it **does not say anything** about whether you allow attributionless copying is allowed. By itself that means that such copying defaults to copyright law's "only with explicit permission", but you can choose to issue such a permission and ther will be no conflict with CC-by-sa.

Comment: @hhh, CC's human-readable overview of CC-by-sa itself says: [Any of the above conditions can be waived if you get permission from the copyright holder.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/). Since you're the copyright holder, you're free to issue such a permission to anyone if you'd like to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point! I tried to summarize findings in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The ip material here is all under the creative commons license, meaning that everyone can already use everything on the site for whatever purpose, so long as they provide attribution.

Comment: -1 Sorry but that is different license to specified above, I want that public is able to use my contributed material without reference to SO or SE: `"under any license or none"`. If someone uses my material for education purposes such as writing a crowd-sourced book, I don't want references to SO or SE to mess things up. If I remove my account due to this kind of evil activity such as patronization or discrimination, I don't have much respect to SE -- I want to make sure anyone, besides SE, is able to work with material, even to create new SE if wanted.

Answer (score -1):

*I am trying to summarize now the key points of the answers.*

> Robert wrote "But you can't change the licensing terms for the stuff posted here.".

**Changing license**

> > CC's human-readable overview of CC-by-sa itself says: Any of the
> >     above conditions can be waived if you get permission from the
> >     copyright holder.. Since you're the copyright holder, you're free to
> >     issue such a permission to anyone if you'd like to. (Henning's comment and some license text)
>
> You can dual-license things, this right cannot be dangered. So yes you can create a new SE if you have permissions from every copyright -holder.
>   But what does the `"waive rights"` actually mean? Is Robert's
>   statement `"But you can't change the licensing terms for the stuff
>   posted here."` correct?

**Termination**

> Robert said that the license is not revocable but parts such as part 2
>   must be fulfilled:
>
> > "This License and the rights granted hereunder will terminate automatically upon any breach --", the section about termination. "2.
> >     Fair Dealing Rights. Nothing in this License is intended to reduce,
> >     limit, or restrict any uses free from copyright or rights " so if
> >     copyright -holders are not allowed to have their material under more
> >     freedom-respecting -license, they can terminate i.e. revoke the
> >     license, right? Can I now drop out the requirement for references in
> >     the license in my contributions, please.

Comment: Note, ${\rm wave}\ne{\rm waive}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you, I cannot yet fully understand the difference between `"to wave"` and `"to waive"`, moved it to English SE [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85158/to-wave-and-to-waive-their-legal-difference-pronunciation-same-but-legal-t).

Comment: To waive something is to choose not to insist on something that you are entitled to insist on. To wave something is to hold it up and move it repeatedly from side to side.